# Sum results of expression containing CountDistinct in Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that requires counting the number of days an event occurred. I have created a Calculated Field that weeds out the dates:

```
=IIF(Fields!ID_ACW.Value > 0, Fields!CallDate.Value, Nothing)
```

By placing this in a CountDistinct expression, each row shows the correct number of distinct days this event occurred.

However, I need to add these results together for each row group's total. I have tried using

```
=Sum(CountDistinct(=IIF(Fields!ID_ACW.Value > 0, Fields!CallDate.Value, Nothing)))
```

and

```
=RunningValue(CountDistinct(=IIF(Fields!ID_ACW.Value > 0, Fields!CallDate.Value, Nothing)),Sum, "DataSet1")
```

, but neither gives me the correct total. Is there something I have missed or is it possible to add an expression to total each row's value?

Comment: Is your current working expression inside a rowgroup?

Comment: Yes, it is inside a row-group.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by adding the row-group's value to the date in the Calculated Field like so:

```
=IIF(Fields!ID_ACW.Value > 0, Fields!CallDate.Value & " " & Fields!CallHour.Value, Nothing)
```

Now I can use
'''
CountDistinct(ACWDay)
'''
And get correct totals across all row-groups.

Is there a cleaner method to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is from memory so it might not be 100% but you should get the idea...

```
=Sum(
CountDistinct(=IIF(Fields!ID_ACW.Value > 0, Fields!CallDate.Value, Nothing), "YourRowGroupName")
)
```

Basically you need to do your CountDistinct within each rowgroup and then sum the results.

Comment: When I tried that, I got an error stating that the scope parameter must be set to a string constant equal to the name of a containing group. This is even with the correct group name entered.

Comment: The group name must be spelled exactly (Case sensitive) and must be in double quotes e.g. `SUM(Fields!MyFields.Value, "myRowGroupName")`

Comment: Yes, that is how I typed it in, double quotes and all. Still gave me the error.